# Line integral confirmation

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the line integral $\int_{C}(x+y)d|z|$, where C is the parametric curve $z(t)=(1+\cos(t),1-\sin(t))$, $t \in [0,\pi]$, is the following correct?

$|z| = \sqrt{\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t)} = \sqrt{1} = 1$

$d|z| =1dt $

$\int_{0}^{\pi}(1+\cos(t) + 1 - \sin(t))dt = 2(\pi -1)$

Comment: $d|z| = \sqrt{\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t)}dt = \sqrt{1}dt = 1dt$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you have is now correct.

Comment: This is a comment.

Comment: @AaronMaroja But this is all the question asked, "is the following correct"?